# Awk cross reference code not working on different platform

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have a cross reference bash script using awk, however it works on my laptop but doesn't work on my other computer :s..

script example is :

```
"C:\cygwin\bin\gawk.exe" -F: "FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a{print a[$1] FS $2}" username.email.txt email.phone.txt > username.phone.txt
```

username.email input:

```
example:email@email.com
```

email.phone.txt input:

```
email@email.com:0123456789
```

username.phone output:

```
example:0123456789
```

so what happens here is if email is in > email.phone.txt, output > username & phone in username.phone.txt cross referencing between the 3 files.

this works fine on another laptop, however doesn't work on another computer.. i get a syntax error & invalid subscript expression.

Example of error:

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[]=;next}  in a{print a[] FS }
gawk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: invalid subscript expression
gawk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[]=;next}  in a{print a[] FS }
gawk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[]=;next}  in a{print a[] FS }
gawk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[]=;next}  in a{print a[] FS }
gawk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: invalid subscript expression
```

Comment: Are you using different shells on your computers? Your script example looks correct for `cmd.exe` (the standard windows command line), but wrong for `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use double-quotes for the body of `awk` commands? `$1` has a special meaning when double-quoted, the values of `$1` are being evaluated as positional arguments and are passed to `awk`, since they don't have values for it, that is why they are empty. Since `awk` sees an empty subscript array it complains it is not a valid array.

Simply single-quote it to solve the problem.

```
"C:\cygwin\bin\gawk.exe" -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a{print a[$1] FS $2}' username.email.txt email.phone.txt > username.phone.txt
```

In general we single-quote the action(s) part to `awk` to pass them as literal strings to not let the shell do its parsing before passing it to `awk`. As mentioned single-quotes pass the string as-is without going through any expansion.

If you still want to go through the pain of using double-quotes, escape the dollar sign to deprive of its special meaning i.e. with an escaped character the dollar variables do not go through expansion ( not recommended in any way)

```
"C:\cygwin\bin\gawk.exe" -F: "FNR==NR{a[\$2]=\$1;next} \$1 in a{print a[\$1] FS \$2}" username.email.txt email.phone.txt > username.phone.txt
```

Comment: By the command path I'd guess the OP is trying to run the script on Windows so he can't use single quotes. The usual suggestion is to put the script in a file and run it as awk -f script to avoid WIndows nightmarish quoting rules rather than try to use double quotes. Or even better install cygwin and run awk from that.